# Rails 3 complex sort by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently creating an App to keep track of my Diablo 3 auctions, and I am having an issue with sorting.

Right now I have an Items page that lists all of my items and information on the MOST RECENT sale.  Every item can have multiple sales, but I only want the most recent sale appearing on the item page.

I have everything appearing correctly, and I am able to sort by the items NAME, GEARSLOT, and iLVL without any issues since they belong to the Item model.

However, it is proving to be tricky to sort by either the sale currency or price.  I have looked this up, and found plenty of solutions that would apply if each item only had 1 sale, but nothing that helps me with sorting by only the most recent association.

index.html.erb

```
<table id="item_list">
  <tr class="header_row">
    <th><%= link_to "Name", :sort => :name %></th>
    <th><%= link_to "Gearslot", :sort => :gearslot %></th>
    <th><%= link_to "Ilvl", :sort => :ilvl %></th>
    <th>Currency</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

<% @items.each do |item| %>
<% last_sale = item.sales.find(:last) %>
<tr>
  <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <td><%= item.Gearslot %></td>
  <td><%= item.iLvl %></td>
  <td><%= Sale::CURRENCYCODE.index(last_sale.currency) %></td>
  <td><%= last_sale.price %></td>
</tr>

....
```

items_controller.rb

```
def index
  @items = Item.order(params[:sort])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @items }
  end
end
```

I can already tell that I might not be doing this the most effective way to begin with, so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This bad code, for security reasons. It is subject to SQL injection. [A solution](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns) from Ryan Bate's  [Railcasts](http://railscasts.com).